# tikz is not positioning my nodes correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

I am using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=green
] (world_node) at (0,0){Scene};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm
] (anchor_node) at (3,0){Anchor Node};
\draw[-stealth] (world_node.east) -- (anchor_node.west) 
    node[near end,left]{};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=pink,
    below left= 0.1cm and 1cm of anchor_node
] (anchor_x_axis){\tiny x-axis};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=pink,
    below right= 0.25cm and  0.25cm of anchor_x_axis
] (anchor_x_axis_label){\tiny x-axis label};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.south west) -- (anchor_x_axis.10) node[near end,left]{};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.260) -- (anchor_x_axis_label.45) node[near end,left]{};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=white!90!blue,
    above left= 0.1cm and 1cm of anchor_node
] (anchor_y_axis){\tiny y-axis};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=white!90!blue,
    above right= 0.25cm and  0.25cm of anchor_y_axis
] (anchor_y_axis_label){\tiny y-axis label};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.north west) -- (anchor_y_axis.345) node[near end,left]{};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.100) -- (anchor_y_axis_label.310) node[near end,left]{};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=white!90!yellow,
    above right= 0.1cm and 1cm of anchor_node
] (anchor_z_axis){\tiny z-axis};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    fill=white!90!yellow,
    right= of anchor_node
] (anchor_z_axis_label){\tiny z-axis label};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.east) -- (anchor_z_axis_label.west) node[near end,left]{};
\draw[-stealth] (anchor_node.45) -- (anchor_z_axis.190) node[near end,left]{};
\node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=1.0cm,
    bottom= of anchor_z_axis_label
] (cloud_status){\tiny cloud status};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I want the node with label "cloud status" below the node labeled "z-axis label". But it just snaps back to (0, 0) where I placed the Scene node.

Comment: Try to replace `bottom=` with `below=`

Answer (score 6):

Your code throws the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/bottom', to which you pas
sed 'of anchor_z_axis_label', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspell
ed it.
```

because you used `bottom=of anchor_z_axis_label` instead of `below=of anchor_z_axis_label` to position the final node.

Whenever you get a number in a red box next to the compile button in Overleaf (as in the below screenshot), don't ignore it. Read the error, figure out what's wrong, and fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mostly off-topic, since your problem is already solved by @Torbjørn T. answer.

Drawing your image I would

- use polar coordinates except for nodes, using them the problem of nodes placements is avoided  "cloud status" which I would place at intersection of "x-axis" and "z-axis labels)
- for all nodes use the same size of nodes shapes,
- enable that longer text in nodes can break into two lines

This changes gives to my opinion more appealing looks if images ..,

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}},
  C/.style = {circle, draw, semithick,
              fill=#1, font=\small,
              text width=4.4em, inner sep=1pt, align=center},
  S/.style = {double, double distance=2pt},
                        ]
\node[C=white, font=\Large]   (r)             {Anchor Node};
% left side
\node[C=blue!15] (s1) at (120:4) {y-axis label};
\node[C=blue!15] (s2) at (150:4) {y-axis};
\node[C=green,S, font=\large] (s3) at (180:4) {Scene};
\node[C=pink!15] (s4) at (210:4) {x-axis};
\node[C=pink!15] (s5) at (240:4) {x-axis label};
% right side
\node[C=yellow!15] (s6) at (30:4)  {z-axis};
\node[C=yellow!15] (s7) at (0:4)   {z-axis label};
%
\node[C=white]   (c) at (s5 -| s7)   {cloud status};
%%%% arrows
    \foreach \i in {1,2,4,5,6,7}
\draw[arr]  (r)  -- (s\i);
\draw[arr, shorten <=1pt]  (s3) -- (r);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**:
It seems, that OP instead that clarify own question write an answer, from which follows, that node `cloud is also connected to root node and it is positioned on the same way as other satellite nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
arr/.style = {draw=gray, ultra thick, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}},
  C/.style = {circle, draw, semithick,
              fill=#1, font=\small,
              text width=4.4em, inner sep=1pt, align=center},
  S/.style = {double, double distance=2pt},
                        ]
\node[C=white,font=\Large]  (r)             {Anchor Node};
% left side
\node[C=blue!15] (s1) at (90:4)  {y-axis label};
\node[C=blue!15] (s2) at (135:4) {y-axis};
\node[C=green,font=\large,S] (s3) at (180:4) {Scene};
\node[C=pink!15] (s4) at (225:4) {x-axis};
\node[C=pink!15] (s5) at (270:4) {x-axis label};
% right side
\node[C=white]     (s6) at (315:4)  {cloud status};
\node[C=yellow!15] (s7) at (0:4)    {z-axis label};
\node[C=yellow!15] (s8) at (45:4)   {z-axis};
%%%% arrows
    \foreach \i in {1,2,4,5,...,8}
\draw[arr]  (r)  -- (s\i);
\draw[arr, shorten <=1pt]  (s3) -- (r);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for your answers. I asked this same question on Discord before finally posting on Stack Overflow. They provided a much more satisfactory answer:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1cm, font=\tiny}]
\path node (anchor) {\normalsize Anchor node}
  +(180:3) node[fill=green] (scene) {\normalsize Scene}
  +(140:3) node[fill=white!90!blue] (y) {\(y\)-axis}
  +(100:3) node[fill=white!90!blue] (ylabel) {\(y\)-axis label}
  +(-140:3) node[fill=pink] (x) {\(x\)-axis}
  +(-100:3) node[fill=pink] (xlabel) {\(x\)-axis label}
  +(40:3) node[fill=white!90!yellow] (z) {\(z\)-axis}
  +(0:3) node[fill=white!90!yellow] (zlabel) {\(z\)-axis label}
  +(-40:3) node (cloud) {cloud status};
\draw[-stealth] (scene) -- (anchor);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (x);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (y);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (z);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (xlabel);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (ylabel);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (zlabel);
\draw[-stealth] (anchor) -- (cloud);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Furthermore, I realize it is below and not bottom (I was following [this tutorial](https://latexdraw.com/block-diagram-in-latex-step-by-step-tikz-tutorial/) which was using below)

Comment: It will be fair if you first show in question what you after! After them claim that your solution gives "much more satisfactory" solution ...